# "De" or "de la" for "Il s'agit de [la?] patience" ?

Tags: grammaire, articles

Translating "It's a matter of patience," I said "Il s'agit de patience," but then I started wondering if I needed *la* there, and was entirely unsure. I don't know what rule to apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Il s'agit **de** patience

or better :

> C'est une question **de** patience.

There is no article when the noun represent something generic:

> *C'est une question **de** temps/principe/confiance*; *il s'agit **de** riz*

When the object is specific, there is an article:

> *La question **du** temps qu'il met pour...; il s'agit **de la** voiture de Pierre*.

Here is an example with *patience* which is here a specific quality compared to others:

> – Quelle est la principale qualité requise pour ce poste ?
>
> – [Il s'agit **de**] **la** patience !

Comment: Why is *la* needed in the third phrasing but not the first or second?

Comment: The [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/patience) states it is an adjectival phrase:  *De patience, loc. adj. Qui est relatif à, qui requiert de la patience. Affaire, école, esprit, exercice, leçon, question de patience. Lorsque onze heures sonnaient, l'Anglais (...) ramassait prestement les bouts de crin (...), les outils délicats, avec lesquels il façonnait ses œuvres de patience (E. de Goncourt, Faustin, 1882, p.306).*